# Draw Windows user Control on WPf Canvas

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have an application where I need to draw different graphics objects on the WPF canvas. I could add Line, Rectangle etc. Now, I need to add a windows user control on the canvas. I can't do it. May I know if we can really do that.
Through the forums I know that WindowsHostControl allow to use windows controls but I couldn't find anything specific like drawing this on Canvas.
Please share on how t do this.

Comment: do you esant to keep your control interactive - i.e. button clickable, comboboxes - selectable etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WindowsFormsHost can be added to a Canvas like any other UIElement. Do it like this:

```
<Window x:Class="FormsHost.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"  
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas>
        <WindowsFormsHost Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="50">
            <wf:MaskedTextBox x:Name="mtbDate" Mask="00/00/0000"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```